# Package 'MimeSharp 1.0.0' was restored using '.NetFramework Version= v4.6.1'

Tags: c#, visual-studio, mime

Package 'MimeSharp 1.0.0' was restored using  '.NetFramework Version= v4.6.1' instead of target framework .netCore 2.2. The package may not be fully compatible

Comment: I'm sure there's a question in here somewhere, I'm just not sure what it is.

Comment: But.... just in case... `MimeSharp` isn't available for .NET Core, which is why you get that message.

Comment: I am coding for downloading file and mime sharp extension is compulsory for that, and in core mime sharp is not available I think but I want a suggestion then what would be the solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that you're trying to reference a .net framework assembly in .net core project. Which is not recommended since:

- .NET Core can run assemblies targeting either .NET Core itself or
  .NET Standard
- .NET Framework can run assemblies targeting either .NET Framework
  itself or .NET Standard

We can find the source repos [here](https://github.com/ujjwol/MimeSharp/tree/master/MimeSharp), checking its .csproj and we can find it targets .net framework. That's why the your error message displays.

1.And it's not available for .net core now(someone else posts similar issue), so I suggest you use it in .net framework project. You can either create a new classlibrary, console app, web-app with .net framework(4.x) to consume this package.

2.Also, if you do need to consume the package in a .net core project for some reason, why not port the MimeSharp from .net fx to .net core yourself since we can access the source code.

See:
[Port .NET Framework libraries to .NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/libraries) and 
[Port your code from .NET Framework to .NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/)